# I have a PC not a mac, and I just purchased an iPhone 4, is there anyway I can get a copy of iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile

I'm trying to figure out if I can update my iPhone to iOS 5 now rather than wait all the way till fall, is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the purpose of this website.
[Take a look please](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can't: you need iTunes 10.5, a mac only application for now.

iOS betas are released for developers to test their applications, not end user to test Apple's.  Unlike many other betas, a bug reporter exists but isn't the main purpose of this.

Also, developers are clearly asked not to install the betas on their main devices (their personal iPhone for example). Not only could doing so result in a very buggy day to day experience, but Apple sometimes releases versions a few days after the previous version expired, literally blocking the device in the meantime (the Purple Screen of Death).

Sorry to announce you just lost a hundred bucks, unless you buy a mac and start programming (this is a nice opportunity isn't it?).

Answer (score 2):

Your iPhone must be linked to a Apple Developer account in order to update to iOS 5. Find someone who has an account and ask them or pay $99 for a developer account and an early upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

IOS 5 is still in beta and available only to Apple Developer program subscribers.